# Magento2: Move Email Address Field above Shipping Address Label on magento checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address

[image]

I want to move Email Address field above the shipping address Label on checkout page, because it looks weird in i-pad version. In which file, I can make change code?? which file I have to override?